# No detail data in a Master/Detail scenario in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I'm still learning Angular in a SPA and I'm in the process of converting an MVC app over to Angular. I have a Master/Detail scenario where the master page is a list of members and the detail page is an individual record for the selected member. I still haven't learned a good way to debug to help figure this out but from what I can see this should be returning data. What I don't know is how to properly display it in the page. The member page is working just fine but the detail page doesn't show any data.

What I can see is that when I click "View" to see the detail I can see that the URL has the correct Web API end point with the correct memberId. When I view that URL end point with the memberId in Fiddler I see the correct data being returned. So, the Web API is working correctly.

This is my app.js file and it's using the `'/memberDetail/:memberId'` route and I'm able to get the `'app/views/memberDetail.html'`page to come up in the browser. So the route should be configured correctly.

```
(function () {

    var app = angular.module('troopApp', ['ngRoute','appFilters']);      //('moduleName', [array of injected modules])

    app.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                controller: 'MembersController',
                templateUrl: 'app/views/members.html'
            })
            .when('/memberDetail/:memberId', {
                controller: 'MembersController',
                templateUrl: 'app/views/memberDetail.html'
            })
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/'});
    });


}());
```

This inside my controller I only pulled some of the code so I don't have too much to scroll through.

```
var MemberDetailController = function ($scope, $routeParams, memberFactory) {
        var memberId = $routeParams.memberId;
        $scope.member = null;

        function init() {
            memberFactory.getMember(memberId)
               .success(function (member) {
                   $scope.member = member;
               })
               .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                   //handle error
               });
        }
        init();
    };

    MemberDetailController.$inject = ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'memberFactory'];

    angular.module('troopApp')
      .controller('MemberDetailController', MemberDetailController);
```

This the memberFactory.js file.

```
(function () {
    var memberFactory = function ($http) {

        var factory = {};

        factory.getMembers = function () {
            return $http.get('/api/MemberApi');
        };

        factory.getMember = function (memberId) {
            return $http.get('/api/MemberApi/' + memberId);
        };

        return factory;
    };

    memberFactory.$inject = ['$http'];

    angular.module('troopApp').factory('memberFactory', memberFactory);

}());
```

This is my HTML.

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Member Detail</h2>
    <p />
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
            <tr>
                <td>Name: </td>
                <td>{{ member.FirstName }} {{ member.LastName }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found my own issue. I consolidated my controllers to be in a single file called membersController.js. So, not thinking about it correctly I set the name of the controller in route to MembersController thinking that it points to the JS file when it should have been the actual name of the detail controller "MemberDetailController".

I changed my app.js file to this:

```
(function () {

    var app = angular.module('troopApp', ['ngRoute','appFilters']);      //('moduleName', [array of injected modules])

    app.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                controller: 'MembersController',
                templateUrl: 'app/views/members.html'
            })
            .when('/memberDetail/:memberId', {
                controller: 'MemberDetailController',
                templateUrl: 'app/views/memberDetail.html'
            })
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/'});
    });

}());
```